# How to fix the installation error with 'car' package

Tags: r

I am getting the below error while trying to install the 'car' package in R. Is there anything wrong I am doing here?

`trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/car_3.0-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 447952 bytes (437 KB)
downloaded 437 KB`

`* installing source package 'car' ...
** package 'car' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Warning: package 'carData' was built under R version 3.5.2
Warning in fun(libname, pkgname) :
  bytecode version mismatch; using eval
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/33904/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/data.table/libs/x64/datatable.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.`

`ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'car'
* removing 'C:/Users/33904/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/car'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/33904/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/car'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\33904\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" C:\Users\33904\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpm23nOy/downloaded_packages/car_3.0-2.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status`

Comment: Are you able to share the method in which you are trying to install the package? When I tried `install.packages('car')` in the R console on Windows, it worked fine.

Comment: `car` imports `rio` which in turn imports `data.table`. It looks like you're missing `data.table`, so maybe try to (re)install `data.table` before installing `car`.

Comment: I tried to install data.table..but it still did not work. I am using the version R 3.3.3. I use the command install.packages('car') to install this package. Is there any other issue that is still causing this problem